# Multiple documents share a commonID, only return one document per commonID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a bunch of documents, this is a smaller prototype (the original documents have more fields, but those are not important for this question):

```
{"_id": {"$oid" : "53fedbcdd1d73a2502de6ae0"}, "commonID": "12345", "name": "Bus tour", "option_name" : "Morning tour"}
```

This document represents a tour option. Multiple tour options are grouped together by the commonID. Now I want a list of unique tours, so not every option. Only one option per tour.

For instance:
A certain tour in Amsterdam is called "Bus tour". There are multiple options like: "Morning tour", "Afternoon Tour", "Evening Tour". I only want one document with the commonID "12345". But this for all the tours in the collection.

I read into mapReduce and Aggregation Pipelines but I couldn't find out how to approach this situation. Maybe you can suggest some options or examples I can read into.

Comment: you want to have a document per commonID with the list of all options ? or just a list of all commonID ?

Comment: @BaptisteL, a document per commonID with the list of all options if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the aggregation framework, your aggregation pipeline should look something like that :

```
collection.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: "$commonID", name : "$name", description : "$description", options: { $addToSet : {option: "$option_name", discrition :"$option_discription" }, ... } }])
```

Depends how you want to group your data

Comment: But for the other options, how can I add those to the same document?

Comment: For example if you have two fields, let's say "description" linked to your commonID and "option_description" linked to the option, you can add them as described in my answer (I updated it)

Comment: Is there a way to get all the fields of a document? Not only for my case, but for people reading this answer. My documents have the same fields, but I can imagine that there is a usecase with some different prototypes but still the commonID principle.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think so, you have to add them nominally

Comment: And with the mapReduce function? Is there a chance it is possible to do such thing with mapReduce? Note: I am using mongodb in Node.JS, like I stated in the tags.

Comment: with map/reduce I'm 100% that it's not possible. For the node.js aspect, it's fairly similar to the mongo syntax (with the standard driver or mongoose)

Comment: Alright! I will just create a loop that does findOne over the array with unique CommonID's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take the below dataset for example:

```
db.test.insert({"commonID": "12345", "name": "Bus tour", "option_name" : "Morning tour"});
db.test.insert({"commonID": "12345", "name": "Bus tour", "option_name" : "Afternoon tour"});
db.test.insert({"commonID": "12345", "name": "Bus tour", "option_name" : "Evening tour"});
db.test.insert({"commonID": "12345", "name": "Car tour", "option_name" : "Evening tour"});
```

For your requirement, you can achieve the below result:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "12345", 
  "name" :    [ "Bus tour", "Bus tour", "Bus tour", "Car tour" ],
  "options" : [ "Morning tour", "Afternoon tour", "Evening tour", "Evening tour" ]
}
```

For every "commonID" you can easily get an associative mapping with two arrays in output, you can consider "name" and "options" together as a key value pair, with name[0] -> key and options[0] -> value.  So, for id -> "12345", there exists four names each with an option. You can remove duplicate key,value mappings in the client API.

The query to acheive this is:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$commonID","name":{$push:"$name"},"options"{$push:"$option_name"}}}])
```

updated w.r.t to your comment:

"a document per commonID with the list of all options if possible!"

Comment: But for the other options, how can I add those to the same document?

Comment: Updated w.r.t your requirement

Comment: Note also you can use $addToSet to get just the unique values of each field. Could be helpful for the `name` field.

Comment: @wdberkeley, yes but it would lose its associativity, in this case.